# Is there any way to use JSF 2.x in JSF1.2 environment

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-1.2

Is it possible to configure  JSF2.x in JSF 1.2.I have to implement few loics using JSF2.1 + primefaces5.2 in JSF 1.2 environment.
If its possible what are the configurations required in web.xml and other configuration files.
I don't know whether this question is correct or not.I am new to JSF.

Comment: You need to migrate the entire app first: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4441713

Answer (score 2):

No you can't. For obvious reasons. Older versions do not support newer functionality and running two different versions at the same time is not supported